# Edit/Update MySQL DB Values from HTML form

Tags: php

I have a form that currently submits values to a mysql database. After each submit is performed the data that was just inserted in to the mysql db is echoed below the form. The form has dynamic input fields. I am know wanting to add the possibility to edit the values previously inserted. I place an edit button that redirects the user to a `personel_edit.php` page in hopes of populating all the input fields accordingly to the `academy_id`. In the code you will see how I do the initial insert and then after do a select to display the information inserted. But I am not sure how to populate this dynamic fields or pass the data to the edit page according to the `academy_id`? [Example](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/personel.php)

After submit - Insert/Display

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$name = $_POST['name'];
$acad_id = $_POST['acad_id'];
$courses_offered=$_POST['courses_offered'];

$query_init  = "INSERT INTO academy (name, academy_id)  VALUES (:name, :acad_id);"; 
$query_prep = $db_con->prepare($query_init);
$insert_result = $query_prep->execute(array(
    "name" => $name,
    "acad_id" => $acad_id
));

$s = 1;
while(isset($_POST['person_fname_' . $s]))
{
    $contact_role = isset($_POST['person_contact_' . $s]) ? 1 : 0;
    $instructor_role = isset($_POST['person_instructor_' . $s]) ? 1 : 0;
    $person_fname = $_POST['person_fname_' . $s];
    $person_lname = $_POST['person_lname_' . $s];
    $person_email = $_POST['person_email_' . $s];
    $person_phone = $_POST['person_phone_' . $s];
    $person_fax = $_POST['person_fax_' . $s];

    $query_init2 = "INSERT INTO person (academy_id, contact_role, instructor_role, first_name, last_name, person_email, person_phone, person_fax) VALUES (:acad_id,:contact_role,:instructor_role,:person_fname,:person_lname,:person_email,:person_phone,:person_fax);";
    $query_prep2 = $db_con->prepare($query_init2);
    $insert_result2 = $query_prep2->execute(array(
        "acad_id" => $acad_id,
        "contact_role" => $contact_role,
        "instructor_role" => $instructor_role,
        "person_fname" => $person_fname,
        "person_lname" => $person_lname,
        "person_email" => $person_email,
        "person_phone" => $person_phone,
        "person_fax" => $person_fax
    ));
    $s++;


}

$db_select  = $db_con->prepare("
SELECT a.name, 
       a.academy_id,
       p.contact_role,
       p.instructor_role,
       p.first_name,
       p.last_name,
       p.person_email,
       p.person_phone,
       p.person_fax
FROM academy a
INNER JOIN person p ON a.academy_id = p.academy_id
WHERE a.academy_id = :acad_id
");
if (!$db_select) return false;
    if (!$db_select->execute(array(':acad_id' => $acad_id))) return false;
    $results = $db_select->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (empty($results)) return false;
    $final_result = '';
    $first = true;
    foreach ($results as $value){
        if($first){
          $first = false;
          $final_result .= "<b>Academy Name: </b>".$value['name']."<b>  ID: </b>".$value['academy_id']."</br>";
        }
          $final_result .= "---------------------PERSONEL-----------------------</br>";
          $final_result .= "<b>First Name: </b>".$value['first_name']."</br><b>Last Name: </b>".$value['last_name']."</br><b>Email: </b>".$value['person_email']."</br>";
          $final_result .= "<b>This person has the role of an instructor: </b>".$value['instructor_role']."</br><b>This person has the role of a contact: </b>".$value['contact_role']."</br>";
          $final_result .= "<b>Phone: </b>".$value['person_phone']."</br><b>Fax: </b>".$value['person_fax']."</br>";        
    }

    $final_result .= '<button name="change" id="change" onClick="check(' . $value['academy_id'].');">Edit</button>';

}

    ?>
```

HTML Form

```
<form action="courses.php" method="POST">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"></br>
Academy<input id="academy_id" name="acad_id" placeholder="Academy ID" type="text" /></br>
            How many courses offered?
            <select name="courses_offered">
                <option value="default">---Select---</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        <div id="course_catalog"></div>
        Personel Information:
        <ul id="pq_entry_1" class="clonedSection">
            <li>
                <input id="person_fname_1" name="person_fname_1" placeholder="Person #1 - First Name" type="text" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input id="person_lname_1" name="person_lname_1" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input id="person_email_1" name="person_email_1" placeholder="Email" type="text" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input id="person_phone_1" name="person_phone_1" placeholder="Phone" type="text" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input id="person_fax_1" name="person_fax_1" placeholder="Fax" type="text" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input id="person_contact_1"  name="person_contact_1" type="checkbox" />Concact
            </li>
             <li>
                <input id="person_instructor_1"  name="person_instructor_1" type="checkbox" />Instructor
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type='button' id='btnAdd' value='add another Person' />
        <input type='button' id='btnDel' value='delete Delete' />   
        </br>
        </br>
    <input value="SAVE" name="submit" type="submit">
</form> 
</body>
See Results:
<?php
echo $final_result;
echo $final_result2;
```

Comment: You have to do an ajax call for inserting as well as updating so that you can send back all the fields as your ajax response and you can populate the values using jquery.

Comment: @issueNo329 can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

After insertion of the data u select the Max(academy_id) and store in variable.

```
 $var_academy_id=Max(academy_id)
```

then pass this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Through your query
if you want to edit your form use hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="update">
```

then check inside post variable value of this hidden field
if update then use update query or if submit then use insert query.